# Wrong rendering of google maps

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps

My map looks like this:

[image: Screen shot]

I don't know what it is, but I think it has connection with style o div, in which it is located:

```
div#col_left {
    width: 140px;
    float: left;
    height:auto;
    margin-bottom:20px; 
}
```

Comment: You'll see on the right side of the map there's an artifact of another section map. (I'm guessing)

Comment: Instead of associating `div` with `col_left`, try using only `#col_left` in your style definition, and also try increasing the width of your map frame as it seems too small to fit-in the map controls.

Comment: I've tested it, it seems like the artifact has something to do with zoom, which is either conflicting with map data cache of the browser, try running your page after cleaning entire browser cache, or alternatively you can use private browsing mode, as it has nothing to do with width of map frame, that I suspected.

Answer (score 0):

I just took [a very the simple V3 example](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple.html) and added your style to the map_canvas div, it worked like a charm without clearing the cache or anything. I'd recommend posting to the [Google Maps JavaScript API V3 forum](http://groups.google.com/group/google-maps-js-api-v3) with a live (publicly accessible) example so that people can have a look at the whole thing.